# ¿Se puede ordenar una columna CLOB que contiene objetos?

Tags: sql, oracle, ordenamiento, clob

Tengo una columna tipo CLOB que almacena un arreglo de objetos que contienen la siguiente estructura:

{"id": 1, "nombre": "auditiva"}

Entonces suponer que tengo la siguiente columna de registros CLOB:

1. [{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
2. [{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
3. [{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}]

y asi con varios registros que su arreglo en el CLOB como minimo contiene un objeto; entonces supongamos que tengo los anteriores registros, ¿es posible ordenar esa columna por el nombre de cada primer objeto de cada registro? ejemplo del resultado deseado

1. [{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
2. [{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
3. [{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías obtener la 5ta ocurrencia de " en el campo CLOB y el caracter siguiente del CLOB y luego ordenar por eso, en tu caso si tienes los registros que dices quedaría:

```
[{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]      > "f
[{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]                                      > "a
[{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}]    > "i
```

Y luego ordenar por este campo para que quede:

```
1) "a
2) "f
3) "i
```

Con esta consulta podrías lograrlo:

```
select columnaCLOB from Tabla
order by SUBSTR(To_Char(columnaCLOB),INSTR(To_Char(columnaCLOB),'"',1,5),2)
```

Si quisieras tomar uno o dos caracteres más desde el " solo sería cuestión de aumentar el número X:

```
select columnaCLOB from Tabla
order by SUBSTR(To_Char(columnaCLOB),INSTR(To_Char(columnaCLOB),'"',1,5),X)
```